# Modelling the Chinese Go game

Tags: alloy

For an university project I'm trying to write the chinese game of Go (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_%28game%29) in Alloy. (i'm using the 4.2 version)

I managed to write the base structure. Go's played on a board 9 x 9 wide, but i'm using a smaller set of 3 x 3 for checking it faster. 
The board is made of crosses which can either be empty or occupied by black or white stones.

```
abstract sig Colour {}
one sig White, Black, Empty extends Colour {}

abstract sig Cross { 
  Status: one Colour, 
  near: some Cross, 
  group: lone Group
}
one sig C11, C12, C13, 
        C21, C22, C23, 
        C31, C32, C33 extends Cross {}

sig Group {
  stones : some Cross, 
  freedom : some Cross
} 

pred closeStones {
  near= 
  C11->C12 + C11->C21 +
  C12->C11 + C12->C13 + C12->C22 +
  C13->C12 + C13->C23 +
  C21->C22 + C21->C11 + C21->C31 +
  C22->C21 + C22->C23 + C22->C12 + C22->C32 +
  C23->C22 + C23->C13 + C23->C33 +
  C31->C32 + C31->C21 +
  C32->C31 + C32->C33 + C32->C22 + 
  C33->C32 + C33->C23
}

fact stones2 {
   all g : Group | 
   all c : Cross | 
     (c.group=g) iff c in g.stones
}

fact noGroup{
  all c : Cross | (c.Status=Empty) iff c.group=none
}

fact groupNearStones {
  all disj c,d : Cross |
  ((d in c.near) and c.Status=d.Status) 
  iff 
  d.group=c.group
}
```

The problem is: following Go rules, every stones must be considered as part of a group. This group is made of all the adiacent stones with the same colour. 
My fact "groupNearStones" should be sufficient to describe that condition, but this way I can't get groups made of more of 3 stones.

I've tried rewriting it in different ways, but either the analizer says it found "0 variables" or it groups up all the stones with the same status, regardless of wheter they're near each other or not.

If you could give me any insight I will be grateful, since i'm breaking my head on this simple matter for days.

Comment: Note: what you call a *group* is usually called a *chain* in Go literature. A group consists of one or more chains sharing fate. (live or die together) These chains need not be connected in the strict sense.

Comment: Good to know. I'm still an amateur at the game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask yourself two questions.

First:  in Go, what constitutes a group?  You say yourself:  it is a set of adjacent stones with the same color.  Not that every stone in the group must be adjacent to every other; it suffices for every stone to be adjacent to another stone in the group.

So from a formal point of view:  given a stone S, the set of stones in the group as S is the transitive closure of the stones reachable through the relation same_color_and_adjacent, or `S.*same_color_and_adjacent`.

Second:  what constitutes being the same color and adjacent?  I think you can define this easily, with what you have.

On a side issue; you may find it easier to scale the model to arbitrary sizes of boards if you reify the notion of rows and columns.

I hope this helps.

[Addendum:]  Apparently it doesn't help enough.  I'll try to be a bit more explicit, but I want the full solution to come from you and not from me.

Note that the point of defining a relation like same_color_and_adjacent is not to eliminate the formulation of facts or predicates in your model, but to make them easier to write and to write correctly.  It's not magic.

Consider first a reformulation of your fact `groupNearStones` in terms of a single relation that holds for pairs of stones which are adjacent and have the same color.  The relation can be defined by modifying your declaration for Cross:

```
abstract sig Cross { 
  Status: one Colour, 
  near: some Cross, 
  group: lone Group,
  near_and_similar : some Cross
}{
  near_and_similar = near & { c : Cross | c.@Status = Status}
}
```

Now your existing fact can be written as:

```
fact groupNearStones2 {
  all disj c,d : Cross |
  d in c.near_and_similar
  iff 
  d.group=c.group
}
```

Actually, I would write both versions of groupNearStones as predicates, not facts.  That would allow you to check that the new formulation is really equivalent to the old one by running a check like:

```
pred GNS_equal_GNS2 {
  groupNearStones iff groupNearStones2
}
```

(I have *not* run such a check; I'm being a little lazy.)

Now, let us consider the problems you mention:

- You never get groups containing more than three stones.  Actually, given the formulation of groupNearStones, I'm surprised you get groups with more than two.  Consider what groupNearStones says:  any two stones in a group are adjacent and have the same color.  Draw a board on a piece of paper and draw a group of five stones.  Now ask whether such a group satisfies the fact groupNearStones.  Say the group is C11, C12, C13, C21, C22.  What does groupNearStones say about the pair C21, C13?

  Do you see the problem?  Are the relations `near` and 'close enough to be in the same group' really the same?  If they are not the same, are they related?

  Hint:  think about transitive closure.
- You never get groups containing a single stone.

  How surprising is this, given that groupNearStones says that c.group = d.group only if c and d are disjoint?  If you never get single-stone groups, then every stone that should be a single-stone group is not classed as being in any group at all, since such a stone must not satisfy the expression s.group = s.group.

  Do you see the problem?

  Hint:  think about *reflexive* transitive closure.

Comment: So should I define a relation, rather than facts? I tried writing "
fact groupNearStones2 {all g : Group | all c: Cross | (c.group=g) iff (c.status=g.stones.status and (c in g.stones.near)) }" which successfully manages to group stones, but still gives me issues (doesn't generate a group with less than two stones, groups up stones that are not near to each other and such).

Comment: No, the point of the relation is not to eliminate facts, but to separate concerns, make the facts easier to write, and make any problems easier to diagnose.

Comment: Thanks. I've reached a solution. I was missing the fact that Alloy as the reflexive transitive closure built-in with the * operator.